# access the path of attribute in python

Tags: python, oop, method-resolution-order

I apologize if I'm not realy good at English. I want to write a function that returns the path of the attribute of a class.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def f(self, a, b):
        pass

class B(A):
    def g(self , a):
        pass

class C(B):
    def L(self , a):
        pass



def rearrange(list_of_class):
    cls = list_of_class
    for Cls in cls.mro():
        pass

rearrange([A,B,C])
c = C()
c.f(10,20)
```

For `c.f(10,20)`, the path is `C-> B-> A` .
So I want to write the function `rearrange(list_of_class)` to return this path .
I use mro() to access all possible paths. Now I have a problem: how can I access the object `c` in `rearrange()` that has not been created before calling `rearrange()`?. I know I can create an object in `rearrange()` but I want to know is it possible to access object  `c` in this way?

Comment: There is something wrong with your code. 1. Wrong spelling of rearrange when calling. 2. List type `cls` can't call mro(). I'm not sure what do you mean by "access c that has not been created", could you explain more about your expect output and difficulty you have met?

Comment: this is not all my codes. this part of my code runs with out error. I use mro() to creat all possible path of all classes define in file. so when I creat an object and use a method of its own  or its parent I should return the path of method like the example . but I don't know how can I use the variable method of object in function 'rearrange' to find its path.  my problem is, from  which one of the classes inthe list, an object created and which method  is udsed. and the bigger problem is function 'rearrange' call befor 'c=C()', it means when function is calling there is no object...

Comment: Your path is simply the prefix of `C.mro()` that ends with something that depends on the attribute you are looking for. `rearrange` doesn' need to take that list of classes as input: all the classes are already on `C.mro()`. It *does* need to take the name of the attribute you are looking for. So `rearrange(C, 'L')` could return `[C]`, `rearrange(C, 'g') == [C, B]`, etc. The instance `c` itself is irrelevant beyond the fact that `c.__class__` is `C`.